# create a list with the results (dataframes) of the same functions applied on a list of inputs in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, foreach

I am using the function text stat_keyness that look at the most frequently appearing words for a specific group of documents in comparison with all the other groups of documents (so basically you input the target group of documents and the output is a dataset containing the words ordered from the most important to the less important and some other columns with some statistics.

I have a a character vector with all the name of the documents groups I want to apply Keynes analysis to:

```
interests_list <- c(unique(data$interest))
```

(it looks like : chr "0" , "340" , "456" etc.. basically each number corresponds to a group of documents)

I can easily apply stat_keyness to a single group of document as follows

```
keyness <- dfm(dfmat_data, groups = "group_interest")

#Calculate keyness and determine audience as target group,  compare frequencies of words 
between target and reference documents. 

result_keyness <- textstat_keyness(keyness, target = "17627")
```

the problem is that I don't want to run stat_keyness for each group individually as I have around 100 groups.
I was thinking to use a for loop, but I am not sure **how to create a list of all the dataframes generated by text stat_keyness**
I wrote this so far, but I don't know how to store all the results I would obtain

```
for(i in interest_list) {textstat_keyness(keyness, target =  i )

}
```

otherwise, I tried with apply but it doesn't work

```
keylist <- lapply(keyness, textstat_keyness(keyness, target = interest_list ))
```

any idea how I can do to obtain my list of data frame in any efficient way?

thank you very much,

Carlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative to the for loop provided by JaiPizGon, is a solution with `lapply`.

```
keylist <- lapply(interest_list, function(i) textstat_keyness(keyness, target = i))
```

Note that lapply is essentially a `for` loop, which always return a list.

The notation used by JaiPizGon is also correct, only you should be careful in growing objects in R - see chapter 2 in "The R Inferno".

So if you are more comfortable using a `for` loop I suggest specifying the size of the list prior to assignment, i.e.:

```
keylist <- vector("list", length(interest_list))

for(i in seq_along(interest_list)) {
  keylist[[i]] <- textstat_keyness(keyness, target = interest_list[i])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried initializing a list and assigning the result of `textstat_keyness` function?
Code:

```
keylist <- list()
for (i in 1:length(interest_list)) {
    keylist[[i]] <- textstat_keyness(keyness, target =  interest_list[i])
}
```